# Unity - Erro: Object reference not set to an instance of an object - Instantiate

Tags: c#, unity3d

Fiz o tutorial do Survival Shooter que pode ser encontrado na asset store do Unity em https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/21028

O jogo está funcionando, mas  tá dando esse seguinte erro no código. Como resolvo isso?

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object EnemyManager.Spawn () (at Assets/Scripts/Managers/EnemyManager.cs:26)
(Instantiate (enemy, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].position, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].rotation);)
```

esse erro aparece justamente quando o jogo começa e os bonecos começam a atacar o player.

O código é o seguinte, que é o mesmo do tutorial do seu canal e do site da unity:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class EnemyManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public PlayerHealth playerHealth;       // Reference to the player's heatlh.
    public GameObject enemy;                // The enemy prefab to be spawned.
    public float spawnTime = 3f;            // How long between each spawn.
    public Transform[] spawnPoints;         // An array of the spawn points this enemy can spawn from.


    void Start ()
    {
        // Call the Spawn function after a delay of the spawnTime and then continue to call after the same amount of time.
        InvokeRepeating ("Spawn", spawnTime, spawnTime);
    }


    void Spawn ()
    {
        // If the player has no health left...
        if(playerHealth.currentHealth <= 0f)
        {
            // ... exit the function.
            return;
        }

        // Find a random index between zero and one less than the number of spawn points.
        int spawnPointIndex = Random.Range (0, spawnPoints.Length);

        // Create an instance of the enemy prefab at the randomly selected spawn point's position and rotation.
        Instantiate (enemy, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].position, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].rotation);
    }
}
```

Comment: Olá @Claudemir, poderia por favor adicionar uma captura de tela do Inspector do objeto EnemyManager - clica nele na hierarchy. Parece que ele não está encontrando os inimigos ou não encontrou o spawnpoint.

Answer (score 6):

#### Entendimento do Problema

O erro `Object reference not set to an instance of an object` acontece quando você trabalha com alguma variável que não foi instanciada.

No Unity o método `Instantiate` pode ser usador de duas formas

1. Instantiate(original: Object);
2. Instantiate(original: Object, position: Vector3, rotation: Quaternion);

> http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html

No teu código você passa `enemy` e o `spawnPoints`

```
Instantiate (enemy, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].position, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex].rotation);
```

E são criados e instanciados em:

```
public GameObject enemy;                // The enemy prefab to be spawned.
public Transform[] spawnPoints;
```

Você passa ele como parâmetro pelo `Inspector` do teu objeto de jogo `EnemyManager`.

Deveria estar alguma coisa assim:

[image: EnemyManagerInspector]

Se estiver faltando algum pode acontecer este problema

#### Soluções Possíveis

Recomendo que veja duas coisas:

1. se o Prefab de todos os personagens existem(zombunny, zombear e hellephant),eles pode ter desaparecido durante a migração para o Unity 5 que aconteceu nas ultimas semanas.
2. Se todos os spawnPoints existem na hierarchy do teu unity conforme imagem abaixo.
   [image: Hierarchy]

Se tuas imagens baterem com a minha é capaz que funcione. Senão é importante que compartilhe mais informações.

Adicione uma captura de tela dos teus elementos para ajudar na investigação se essa resposta não te ajudar.

Comment: Oi Nills, eu tive o mesmo problema com instancia mas é com conversação 'MessagingClientReceiver().start' se quiser me ajudar me fala que eu fasso a pergunta certinho e mando o link

Comment: @LeonardoV.DeGasperin como você está usando o Instantiate com o MessagingClient?

Não precisa convidar um usuário para abrir tua dúvida, crie e descreva bem o teu problema que outras pessoas poderão te ajudar. Abraço.

Comment: oi Nils eu sei que não precisa mas poderíamos compartilhar respostas das perguntas foi nisso que pensei. Porém estou aqui para ajudar vou te passar um link que me ajudou muito la tem um post meu vou passar depois, pois tenho que reencontrar, esse site é de um desenvolvedor de games da game desenvelopent team muito bom e me ajudou muito http://darkgenesis.zenithmoon.com   espero que o ajude também.

Comment: http://darkgenesis.zenithmoon.com/DarkGenesisForums/topic/ch5-messagingclientreceiver/   aqui eu obtive as respostas aqui meu post responde a sua pergunta perfeitamente. meu post ta la para baixo eu perguntei para o Simon em 4 de Julho

Comment: @LeonardoV.DeGasperin obrigado pela dica, o cara dá uma força legal para a galera que quer desenvolver.